# Is there a way to parse a multi-line-string in python into a list of lists

Tags: python, string, nested-lists

I am trying to turn something like this string with multiple lines:

"apple, orange, cat\n, 100, 200, 300\n, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6\n"

into something like this nested-list where each word\number is an element of each line which is an element of a bigger list:

```
 [['apple', 'orange','cat'], 
        ['100', '200', '300'], 
        ['0.3', '0.5', '0.6']]
```

I am also working on a large scale so way more than 3 lines

I can't figure it out on my own. Please help.

I have already tried to use .append, list(), plain old [], .split where I split the lines at the `"\n"` and `","`.

None of those worked and the closest I got was a list of the separate numbers\words but with no idea on how to split them

Comment: Are you sure you want each inner element to be in a single-element list? Why not `[['apple','orange','cat'],['100','200','300'],['0.3','0.5','0.6']]`?

Comment: yes sorry this is what I needed thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str="your data string"

list=str.split('\n')

for i in range(len(list)):
       list[i]=list[i].split(',')

print (list)
```

This is the bigger and easier to understand method...or you could list comprehension as said by @user8426627

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = [ [s.strip() for s in line.split(',') if s] for line in text.split('\n') if line]
```

Comment: This works. Thank you very much! (you just have a small typo. I think you mean s.split instead of  text.split)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = "apple, orange, cat\n, 100, 200, 300\n, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6\n"
>>> line_split = s.split('\n')
>>> line_split
['apple, orange, cat', ', 100, 200, 300', ', 0.3, 0.5, 0.6', '']
>>> word_split = [line.split(',') for line in line_split]
>>> word_split
[['apple', ' orange', ' cat'], ['', ' 100', ' 200', ' 300'], ['', ' 0.3', ' 0.5', ' 0.6'], ['']]
```

OR

```
[line.split(',') for line in s.split('\n')]  // One Liner
```

You'll have to clean up the unwanted strings

**PS**

Your string seems to be a Comma separated value (CSV). You could leverage pandas for better manipulation

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(s))
     apple   orange    cat
NaN  100.0    200.0  300.0
NaN    0.3      0.5    0.6
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes  it is a CSV and that is very helpful!

Comment: If you have a file you could load directly using `pd.read_csv(file_name)`. Glad that helped. If you find my answer helpful please accept by clicking the tick on the answer @GhamrSaeed